# Newman Testrail integration - Error: No test cases were found

Tags: postman, integration, testcase, newman, testrail

peoples! =)
Got some problem)
I ve got Windows 10 64Bit and use newman-reporter-testrail
On the Postman: I have two methods, each with three tests.
On TestRail: three test cases for these tests and a testrun with them.

1. I created system variables for windows: TESTRAIL_USERNAME, TESTRAIL_API key, TESTRAIL_RUNID, TESTRAIL_DOMAIN and filled them in.
2. Inserted the code from the cases in the TestRail tests postman.
3. When I run the Newman collection in JSON with a reporter I get the error "Newman-reporter-testrail: no test cases were found".

[Screenshot Newman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Wl8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally I got it! In Postman my tests were arranged one after the other without space separation. And reporter can't find them. But it works when I run them on Newman only.